# python percent change consecutive items in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help dropping the NaN from the list generated in the code below. I'm trying to calculate the geometric average of the list of numbers labeled 'prices'. I can get as far as calculating the percent changes between the sequential numbers, but when I go to take the product of the list, there is an NaN that throws is off. I tried pandas.dropna(), but it didn't drop anything and gave me the same output. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np

prices = [2,3,4,3,1,3,7,8]

prices = pd.Series(prices)
prices = prices.iloc[::-1]

retlist = list(prices.pct_change())

retlist.reverse()
print(retlist)

calc = np.array([x + 1 for x in retlist])

print(calc)

def product(P):
    p = 1
    for i in P:
        p = i * p
    return p

print(product(calc))
```

Answer (score 0):

`retlist` a list, which contains NaN.

you can add a step to get rid of NaN by using the following code:

`retlist = [i for indx, i in enumerate(retlist) if filter[indx] == True]`

After this you can follow with the other steps. Do note that the size of the list changes